# Solr: How to exclude texts with negative meaning while searching

Tags: solr, full-text-search, fuzzy-search

I want to list all the documents which have steel wires in its product field.
Currently the query is resulting with all the documents which matches steel wires in the product filed. But the problem is with following types of sentences.

```
"All types of wires excluding steel wires"
```

The solr query returns this document in result list, which I don't want as it is actually not type of steel wires.

Please help me out.

Comment: Since I dont know your entire corpus of data, what i can suggest is figure out certain rules to see what are the common things in sentences you need to exclude. For example, `excluding` is a word which may be coming in all your sentences, then write a query/rule take all minus the sentences which contains this